# Defining JPA(Hibernate) Entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two database tables

**Tags**

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `tags` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `tag_entity` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('live','deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'live',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**tags_parent**

```
CREATE TABLE `tags_parent` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('live','deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'live',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

In tags_parent, both tag_id & parent_id is ID of tags table.
One tags can have multiple parent / multiple child.

How do I define JPA Entities?

I am trying something like this but I can't visualize better :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tags")
public class Tag implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String description;

    @Column(name="main_id")
    private int mainId;

    private String status;

    @Column(name="tag_entity")
    private String tagEntity;

    @Column(name="tag_quality_score")
    private float tagQualityScore;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="tags_parent",
    joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false,updatable=false)},
    inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id", insertable=false,updatable=false)})
    private List<Tag> tag;
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? It's an Entity with self reference relationship.

Comment: I am trying the JoinTable with both joinColumns & inverseJoinColumns pointing to tags table?

Comment: can you please share your actual code?

Comment: You said `can have multiple parent / multiple child`, then it should be `ManyToMany`?!

Comment: Ok. but what about join condition?

Comment: In that case there should be two collections, one for children and the second for parents.

Comment: Yes, I solved this .